# Smoothness of $f(x)/(1+|f(x)|)$ where $f \in C^1(E)$ for $E$ an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

(a) Show that if $E$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and $f \in C^1(E)$ then the function

$$F(x) = \frac{f(x)}{1+|f(x)|}$$

satisfies $F \in C^1(E)$.

(b) Extend the results of part (a) to $f \in C^1(E)$ for $E$ an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

**Hint part (a):** *Show that if $f(x) \neq 0$ at $x \in E$ then $$F'(x)=\frac{f'(x)}{(1+|f(x)|)^2}$$ and that for $x_0 \in E, f(x_0)=0$ then $F'(x_0)=f'(x_0)$ and that $lim_{x \rightarrow x_0} F'(x)=F'(x_0)$*

**Comments:** Showed part (a), but I can not generalize to the $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both (a) and (b) are best dealt with simultaneously, by writing $F$ as the composition of $f$ with the function 
$$\phi(t) = \frac{t}{1+|t|} , \quad t\in\mathbb R$$ 
Note that $\phi$ lives on the real line, regardless of what the domain of $f$ is.

Since the composition of $C^1$ functions is $C^1$ (chain rule), it remains to show that $\phi\in C^1$. Which amounts to direct computation of $\phi'(t)$ for $t\ne 0$, coupled with the observation that 
$$\phi'(0) = \lim_{t\to0}\frac{\phi(t)}{t}=1$$

---

For the sake of completeness, I prove a more general statement which also handles the vector-valued case.

**Claim.** *If $g:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$ is continuous on $\mathbb R^n$ and $C^1$ on $\mathbb R^n\setminus\{0\}$, then the map  $\phi(x) = xg(x)$ is  $C^1$ on $\mathbb R^n$.*

**Proof**. We can focus on one component of $\phi$, say $\phi_i(x) = x_i g(x)$. By the chain rule, 
$$\nabla \phi_i(x) = e_i g(x) + x_i \nabla g(x),\quad x\ne 0$$ where $e_i$ is the $i$th basis vector. Therefore, 
$\nabla \phi_i$ is continuous on $\mathbb R^n\setminus\{0\}$ and has limit $e_i g(0)$ as $x\to 0$. Also, 
observe that $$\phi_i (x) = x_i g(0) + o(|x|),\quad x\to 0$$
which implies $\phi_i$ is differentiable at $0$, with the derivative $e_i g(0)$. $\Box$

Comment: Please could you explain a little better, because I did not understand why this solves the problem (b).

Comment: @Croos The composition of differentiable functions is differentiable. This is what the chain rule says. It also gives a formula for the derivative of composition: $\nabla (\phi\circ f) = \phi'(f) \nabla f$. This is a product of  continuous functions, hence continuous.

Comment: It is not clear to me how to do $\phi$ composed with $f$ because $\phi: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $f: E \rightarrow E$, $E \subset \mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: @Croos Oh, $f$ is vector-valued? Where in your question does it say that?

Comment: How $f \in C^1(E)$ do not have to $f:E \rightarrow E$? The wording is exactly as I have typed or am I interpreting wrong.

Comment: @Croos The set in parentheses describes the domain of functions. It does not also describe the codomain, unless the author of your textbook was on drugs. Check the definition to see if s/he was.